# Criar procedure para ajustar preço conforme condições (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure

Em um BD de uma livraria preciso criar uma procedure para reajustar a coluna preço conforme o percentual e o gênero informados (utilizando controle de transação). Como eu devo fazer?

```
create table livro (
liv_ID      int not null constraint PKcod_livro primary key,
aut_ID          int not null,
gen_ID      int not null,
liv_Titulo  varchar(100) not null,
liv_Preco   decimal(10,2) not null,
constraint  fkLivAut foreign key (aut_Id) references autor(aut_Id),
constraint  fkLivGen foreign key (gen_Id) references genero(gen_Id));
```

```
create table genero (
gen_ID  int not null constraint PKGenero primary key,
gen_Nome varchar(50) not null );
```

Comment: O que significa "utilizando controle de transação"? Seria definir a transação de forma explícita, usando BEGIN TRANSACTION / COMMIT?

Comment: Como é informado o percentual de reajuste? Por exemplo, para um reajuste de 15,2%, é informado 15.2 ou 0.152?

Comment: Isso, usando BEGIN. O percentual é por exemplo 15.2

Answer (score 2):

Considerando-se que o parâmetro de reajuste é informado como um valor numérico real. Por exemplo, se o reajuste é de 12,5%, o valor passado como parâmetro está na forma 12.5

Para calcular o novo preço do livro, o valor percentual do reajuste é dividido por 100 e a seguir somado a 1. O preço atual do livro é então multiplicado pelo resultado dessa operação.
Por exemplo:

```
  12,5 / 100 = 0,125
  Fator de multiplicação = 1 + 0,125 = 1,125
```

Se o preço atual do livro é R$ 122,00, então temos

```
  Novo preço do livro = R$ 122,00 * 1,125 = R$ 137,25
```

> Se o parâmetro de gênero é informado como código (valor numérico e inteiro), temos:

```
-- código #1 v3 -- gênero é informado como código numérico
CREATE PROCEDURE Atualiza_Preço 
                 @pGênero int, 
                 @pPercentual decimal (5,2)
as
begin
declare @Fator decimal (10,5);
set @Fator= (1 + (@pPercentual / 100));

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE livro
   set liv_Preco*= @Fator
   where gen_ID = @pGênero

COMMIT;

end;
go
```

---

> Mas se o parâmetro de gênero é informado como denominação (texto), temos

```
-- código #2 v3 -- gênero é informado como texto
CREATE PROCEDURE Atualiza_Preço 
                 @pGênero varchar(50), 
                 @pPercentual decimal (5,2)
as
begin
declare @Fator decimal (10,5);
set @Fator= (1 + (@pPercentual / 100));

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE L
   set liv_Preco*= @Fator
   from livro as L
        inner join genero as G on G.gen_ID = L.gen_ID
   where G.gen_Nome = @pGênero

COMMIT;

end;
go
```